# How to use OrientDB in a SailsJS App

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, orientdb, waterline

I am new to NodeJS and SailsJS, was working with Rails or PHP before.

I want to use SailsJS together with OrientDB. What would be the best approach? I found two options so far, but the amount of information isn't that great (yet).

1. Go with [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) and this [sails adapter for orientdb](https://github.com/gauravdhiman/sails-orientdb-binary)
2. Go one level deeper and use the [binary adapter from nodejs](https://github.com/codemix/oriento)

Any help, tips, hints would be greatly appreciated. I am a bit lost but very excited to understand more about these great tools.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have figured out the answer by now but for future reference here's mine.

### Adapter vs OrientDB driver

There are currently 3 OrientDB adapters for Waterline/SailsJS that I know of:

- sails-orientdb-binary (as referred by you);
- [sails-orientdb](https://github.com/vjsrinath/sails-orientdb);
- [waterline-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb).

Given the amount of code, commits and time spent on each I would say is better to use one of these (and probably contribute) than to go down the other route. Using one of these with SailsJS should be plug 'n play and they should also be compatible with blueprints controllers (I say *should* as my experience really is waterline and not so much SailsJS). On the other hand, there may be a slight performance penalty as all queries will go through waterline and adapter before they reach Oriento. Only if performance is absolutely critical I would go directly to Oriento and even so both sails-orientdb and waterline-orientdb expose a `.getDB()` method that return a native Oriento `db` object. So the adapters give you Oriento plus validations plus automatic class creation (through models) plus easy integration with SailsJS, the best of both worlds :)

### Which adapter to use

#### sails-orientdb-binary

This is the one I have the least experience with.

- Last commit: Nov 8, 2014 (out of 4 commits);
- Waterline interfaces implemented: not sure, not mentioned in the package.json;
- Automated tests: no travis.yml or indication that it passes waterline-adapter-tests;
- "oriento": "~0.3.1": this is fairly old and does not support OrientoDB 2.0.

#### sails-orientdb

This seems the oldest adapter and one I have some experience with.

- Last commit: Dec 25, 2014 (out of 45 commits);
- Waterline interfaces implemented: `semantic`, `queryable`. No `associations` interface which means waterline core will handle the joins which will not make the most out the graph specific commands;
- Automated tests: travis.yml set up, but if you got to travis-ci.org/vjsrinath/sails-orientdb it says 0 passing 1 failing;
- "oriento": "^0.3.2": once again an old version of oriento.

#### waterline-orientdb

This one is a fork of sails-orientdb and seen lots of progress recently.

- Last commit: Feb 26, 2015 (out of 421 commits);
- Waterline interfaces implemented: `semantic`, `queryable`, `associations` and `migratable`. Joins are performed by a singe `SELECT` query with fetch plan;
- Automated tests: travis.yml set up. Besides the generic 225 waterline-adapter-tests it has additional 28 unit tests and 68 integration tests all passing in both OrientDB v1.7.10 and v2.0.2;
- "oriento": "~1.1.0": latest version as of now.

So, at the risk of sounding partial, I'm the developer of waterline-orientdb, I believe waterline-orientdb is currently the most mature OrientDB adapter for SailsJS. It has a richer feature, it's more up to date and is better tested.

**UPDATE:** waterline-orientdb is now called [sails-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb) and is maintained by the developers of the mentioned 3 adapters.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply! I also added a pull request to sailsjs to add sails-orientdb to the list of available waterline adapters in the readme. Maybe you want to add yours as well?

Comment: You're welcome. I'll look into adding waterline-orientdb to sailsjs' readme, thanks for the suggestion.